# mcstrans erased, but it erased multiple packages with it and system is broken

Tags: redhat, yum, packages, dependencies

I erased `mcstrans` of my Red Hat system, but it erased with it a lot of other packages. Now yum is not working (python is missing), and I cannot access the server via ssh because `libfipscheck.so.1` is missing.

How can I get yum and OpenSSH to work again?

Comment: How did you remove the packages? What commands did you use?

Comment: I used yum erase mcstrans

Comment: Once i get yum working again, should "yum info undo ID" do the trick to get the erased packages installed again?

Answer (score 1):

Edited based on new information!

Since you used `yum erase`, the configuration files for the packages will still exist. I think you can recover from this, but it might be tedious. As a result, you have two options at this point:

### Option One:

Attempt to get yum and OpenSSH working again by tracking down each package that needs to be installed. You'll probably need to cull log files for errors to determine the packages you need. Obviously python is one of them, so grab the `rpm` for the Python version you need and `rpm -i` it.

### Option Two:

[image: If nothing else, it'll be a good typing exercise.]

Since I know you have fantastic backups and a great restoration procedure, I know recovering from backups will take just a few minutes. Certainly less time than attempting to undo the damage by hand.